# Phabricator repository - git can't read it after it is cloned

Tags: git, phabricator

I'm asking this here because the official support site is all buggy, and I can't really find anything there.

I have setup Phabricator and I am able to successfully clone repositories. They are located at `/var/repo/<repo_number>`

Right after the repo is fetched, if I click on it, I get all sorts of error messages, like the one below:

```
Unable to Retrieve Paths
Command failed with error #128! COMMAND git ls-tree -z -l 
'4a05536ecf9ae60cc53de73d1fcd202466ce42fb':'' STDOUT (empty) STDERR fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /var) Stopping     at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

Seems like a permission error, but I can't figure out what it is. I hoped Phabricator's install script would handle these directory and permission stuff. Apparently not.

I also get this security alert, every time I open the repo's page.
`SELinux is preventing /usr/bin/git from getattr access on the file /var/repo/8/HEAD.` Don't really know what that means.

Going crazy with this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What's buggy about the site?

Comment: Anyways, not really enough information here to make a guess. How did you install Phabricator? Are you running SELinux?

Comment: Installed it as per the documentation. Used the installation script, followed the instructions. Then after successful access to the frontend, fixed some issues. None related to git, btw.

Comment: We don't officially support SELinux, so the easiest path is to not use it. I pointed you to the upstream task.

Answer (score 1):

SELinux is likely the culprit, and we're not really experts at this distribution. There are some hints on the upstream from other admins who have successfully configured SELinux. See https://secure.phabricator.com/T4947